# Time Complexity of the programs

Tags: pseudocode

time complexity.

I think so it may be 'o(n log n)'.please help me with the answer.

```
def f()
    ans = 0
    for i = 1 to n:
        for j = 1 to log(i):
            ans += 1
    print(ans)
```

Comment: This is not C...

Comment: `I think so it may be 'o(n log n)'` ... you think correctly :-) ... BTW this is Python code, not C.

Comment: This is not Python either.

Comment: @blhsing i dont need any language issues...just need what's the runtime?

Comment: @VigneshKumarS If you don't want to adhere to any particular language syntax you should tag this question with `pseudocode` instead of `python-3.x`.

Comment: @blhsing done with your opinion Mr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is O(n log(n) )

Note: it is customary to write (worst case) complexity as big O. Small O (or a greek letter omega) is reserved for something else.